# Calculate Number of Unique Combination of Numbers

Tags: combinations

I want to find the total of possible unique combinations of numbers

example:

- 1234 = 24 combinations
- 1233 = 12 combinations
- 55666 = 10 combinations

can I use math formula to calculate this ?

thanks

Comment: You should look up Multinomial coefficients.

Comment: formula: $\frac{(n_1+\dots+n_k)!}{n_1!\times\dots\times n_k!}$. Applying it on third example: $\frac{(2+3)!}{2!\times3!}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a string of length 5: $$ABCDE$$
How many different permutations of this string exist? You have 5 possible letters for Position 1, 4 for Position 2, 3 for Position 3, 2 for Position 4 and 1 for Position 5.
So in total: $5!$

Now look at the following string: AABCD
Still, you'd have $5!$ permutations of this string. But not all of them are different as we have 2 A's. The positions of the A's can be switched and the string doesn't change. How many ways are there to switch the A's in a string?

$$2!$$

So the answer would be: $$\frac{5!}{2!} = 60$$

Comment: I don't understand the second example,
what about the combination of 'AABBC' ?

Comment: In each of the $5!$ permutations of $AABBC$ you can switch the positions of the 2 A's and the 2 B's and the string does not change. How many permutations(not different) are there of the string 'AA' or the string 'BB'. $2!$. So you get $$\frac{5!}{2!2!}$$.

One more example. For 'AAABC' you'd get $$\frac{5!}{3!}$$.
Does this make it more clear? What don't you understand exactly?

Comment: so for 'ABCCDDD' the formula is 7!/2!3! right ?

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I have my doubt with this solution. Correct me if I am wrong. The calculation that in `AABCD` the combinations of `AA` are `2!` does not consider whole combinations like `ABACD`, `ABCDA`, `ABCAD`. These each have '2!' combination when switching `A`. So the final unique combinations for 'AABCD' would be far less than 60.

Comment: Thats why you divide by $2!$. Look, in total you have $5!$ permutations. But to every single permutation there is another different permutation, that looks exactly the same. This is the one that comes from switching the $A$'s. So you count twice as much permutations as you actually wanted, thus you need to divide by $2$, which is $2!$. Hope this clarifies it. If not, let me know